# Data error (cyclic redundancy check)

Tags: vb.net

It's the first time I see this error. Anyone know what this mean? (and if there's a fix)

> System.IO.IOException: Data error (cyclic redundancy check).
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
> at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive)
> at System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive)

Comment: This tends to mean there is a corruption on the disk - backup and use a new drive!

Comment: @Oded Sounds like it's too late for backup. :)

Comment: @bzlm - For other files that may still be recovered before corruption hits them too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to run CHKDSK from a command prompt.

Regarding to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check):

> A cyclic redundancy check (CRC) or
>   polynomial code checksum is a hash
>   function designed to detect accidental
>   changes to raw computer data, and is
>   commonly used in digital networks and
>   storage devices such as hard disk
>   drives. A CRC-enabled device
>   calculates a short, fixed-length
>   binary sequence, known as the CRC code
>   or simply CRC, for each block of data
>   and sends or stores them both
>   together. When a block is read or
>   received the device repeats the
>   calculation; if the new CRC does not
>   match the one calculated earlier, then
>   the block contains a data error and
>   the device may take corrective action
>   such as rereading or requesting the
>   block be sent again, otherwise the
>   data is assumed to be error free
>   (though, with some small probability,
>   it may contain undetected errors; this
>   is the fundamental nature of
>   error-checking).

Answer (score 1):

1. Open command prompt.
2. Run `CHKDSK driveletter: /f`
3. Follow the steps prompted.
4. Disk should be corrected now.